# Won't Let me Add Float to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Currently, i'm trying to implement a method that stores two UITextField values (after a user has typed it in) in two seperate arrays. However, when I ran the program with the console, the NSLog of each array returned null values (didn't insert the floats).

I tried switching to int, but it says there are incompatibility issues. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
-(IBAction)logSet:(id)sender {
    [repsUsed insertObject:[reps.text floatValue] atIndex:0];
    [weightUsed insertObject:[weight.text floatValue] atIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%@", repsUsed);
    NSLog(@"%@", weightUsed); 
}
```

Comment: try [repsUsed addObject:textfield.text];

Comment: have u allocinit array or directly insertobject init... if u dnt then first alloc init array den insertobject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSMutable can only add objects and float, int are not object type for inserting float values make it a object by

> [repsUsed insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[reps.text floatValue]] atIndex:0];

Comment: You have a ']' in the wrong place.  Should be two after 'floatValue'; one after 'atIndex:0'.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot insert the float value or int value directly into an array. Instead you can directly insert a string value. when you read you can convert it into float.

Try using

```
[repsUsed insertObject:reps.text atIndex:0];
[weightUsed insertObject:weight.text atIndex:0];
```

when you read an array. you can use like this.

```
float val1 = [[repsUsed objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
float val2 = [[weightUsed objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: i didn't tried the code that Challenger Posted here. it also may help

Answer (score -3):

Try This

```
 [repsUsed addObject:[reps.text floatValue]];
 [weightUsed addObject:[weight.text floatValue]];
```

Comment: float needs to be put into a "`NSNumber`" object in order to be added to an "`NSMutableArray`"